# Can't seem to write to the status register of nRFL2401+

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, spi, embedded, nrf24l01

So I've been playing around with nRF2401+ radio module lately but been having a few issues. One of them (which could be the cause of the second one) is not being able to properly set the `Status` register.

So the default value of the status register reads `0xE` as shown below. Now In the initialization, I need to clear the IRQ bits by writing `1` so it reads `0x7E` but it doesn't seem to change at all.

[image]

Below is the attached capture from the logic analyzer. Note that `0x07` refers to the address of `Status` register.  `0x0` refers to `read` operation while `0x2` refers to `write`. You can see the last line is where i'm reading the status register and it reads `0x0E` instead of `0x7E` which I wrote.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstood how it works. You can't write it to 0x7E yourself. The bits get set to '1' by the chip only when a corresponding IRQ event happens.

When the chip has set any of these bits high, they are cleared by the user, by writing a '1' bit to the location you want to clear/acknowledge back to '0'.

So when the register is 0x0E, no interrupts are pending, and there is nothing to clear.